# Chef 11 Regenerate validation key

Tags: chef-infra

I can't get my nodes setup, so I am going to try and regenerate my validator key. The instructions to regenerate the key for the old chef 10 is located [here](http://wiki.opscode.com/display/chef/Common+Errors)

I've tried deleting /etc/chef-server/-validator.pem and restarting the server. I expect the key to be regenerated, but so far it hasn't been recreated.

Here are the steps for chef 10 I am trying to translate to chef 11.

```
$ ls -l /etc/chef/validation.pem
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1676 2011-07-14 11:44 /etc/chef/validation.pem
$ sudo rm /etc/chef/validation.pem
$ sudo /etc/init.d/chef-server restart
 * Restarting chef-server
 ~ Killing pid 10783 with INT
 ~ In 12051
   ...done.
$ ls -l /etc/chef/validation.pem
-rw------- 1 chef chef 1679 2011-07-14 11:55 /etc/chef/validation.pem
```

Here are my steps for chef 11(not working) I have sanitized my company name to read ""

```
ls -l /etc/chef-server/<myOrg>-validation.pem
sudo rm /etc/chef-server/<myOrg>-validation.pem
sudo chef-server-ctl restart
ls -l /etc/chef-server/<myOrg>-validation.pem
ls: cannot access <myOrg>-validation.pem: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the webui as an admin.  Edit the client "chef-validator" and check the box for "Regenerate Private Key".  Then copy/paste it into /etc/chef-server/chef-validator.pem and everywhere else you need it.